# How to use value from a SOQL Query within a For Loop?

Tags: apex, soql

I have an after trigger that runs when a new opportunity is created. My end goal is to select the Salesforce Record ID value from another type of Opportunity and use that value to update a custom field on another opportunity record of a different record type.

I have multiple record types on the opportunity object.

The last loop in my code doesn't work obviously, but I am trying to use the Opportunity__c values returned in "custOpps" inside of that for loop at the bottom so I can copy the value into the "Link_To_Related_Opportunity__c" field

```
  static Id customerOpportunityRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Customer').getRecordTypeId();

  Set<Id> custOppIds = new Set<Id>();
  Set<String> custInvoiceIds = new Set<String>();
  List<Opportunity> custOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
 List<Opportunity> oppRecordsToUpdate= new List<Opportunity>();

public void OnAfterInsert(List<Opportunity> newOpportunityList) {

  for(Opportunity opp : newOpportunityList) {
            if( opp.RecordTypeId == customerOpportunityRecordTypeId && opp.Invoice_ID__c != '') {
                custInvoiceIds.add( opp.Invoice_ID__c );
                custOppIds.add( opp.Id );
            }
        }

// other type of opportunity
custOpps = [SELECT Id, name, Opportunity__c, Invoice_ID__c FROM Invoices__c WHERE Invoice_ID__c = : custInvoiceIds ];

// loop over new opportunity records again
for(Opportunity opp : newOpportunityList) {
  Opportunity oppToUpdate = new Opportunity();
  oppToUpdate.Id = opp.Id;
  oppToUpdate.Link_To_Related_Opportunity__c = custOpps.Opportunity__c // this is the part where I need assistance
  oppRecordsToUpdate.add(oppToUpdate);
}

update oppRecordsToUpdate;


} // end method
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        if( opp.RecordTypeId == customerOpportunityRecordTypeId && opp.Invoice_ID__c != '') {
```

You should compare to `null` or use `String.isBlank()`. Empty strings are not stored in the database.

```
custOpps = [SELECT Id, name, Opportunity__c, Invoice_ID__c FROM Invoices__c WHERE Invoice_ID__c = : custInvoiceIds ];
```

Here, you need to create a `Map<String, Invoice__c>`. (I'm assuming `Invoice_Id__c` is a `String` value). Iterate over the result of this query and place each record into the Map, keyed on its Invoice Id.

Then, here,

```
  oppToUpdate.Link_To_Related_Opportunity__c = invoiceMap.get(opp.Invoice_Id__c);
```

you use the Map to get your related record Id without iterating over the list.

As Adrian rightly points out in the comments, if `Invoice_Id__c` is not an External Id field with a uniqueness constraint applied, you should be prepared to handle the situation where multiple `Invoices__c` records are returned for a single Id.

Comment: Worth noting potential collisions.